# browse .net application in .net6 with docker cause a problem

Tags: asp.net, docker, dockerfile

I have this application as you can see that I run in IIS Express :

[image]

So I want to run it on docker so the docker file is generated :

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Docker/Docker.csproj", "Docker/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Docker/Docker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Docker"
RUN dotnet build "Docker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Docker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Docker.dll"]
```

So I create the image as you can see with this command :

```
docker build -t containername/tag -f docker/Dockerfile .
```

The image is created so I want to run my container using this :

```
docker run -d -p 42419:42419 --name apitest containername/tag:latest
```

The container is created but when I call this url `http://localhost:42419/swagger/index.html` I can't see the swagger page .Why?

Comment: It listens on port 80.

Comment: Did you try `docker run -d -p 80:42419 ....`?

Comment: @Eldar I did it ,But it didn't work

Comment: Ah sorry it's in reverse order. So internal ip on the right external on the left : `42419:80`

Comment: @Eldar I checked it too ,same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application needs to have the environment variable set to 'Development' for Swagger to be available. It's not available in production which is what Docker defaults to.

You can add the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable on your run command like this

```
docker run -d -p 42419:80 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development --name apitest containername/tag:latest
```

You can also add it to the Dockerfile, if you want Development to be the default by adding

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

somewhere in the 'final' part of the Dockerfile.

A third option is to modify your `startup.cs` file and remove the check for the environment variable when it sets up Swagger. That way, it'll always be available no matter what.

Comment: Thanks kian it works .would you please change the port:docker run -d -p 42419:80 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development --name apitest containername/tag:latest

Comment: So you mean without defining the variable I can see the service for example http://localhost:42419/WeatherForecast

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Yes, the service is available even if Swagger is not. I think the reasoning for not including Swagger is that it might help hackers to be able to see all your API calls if Swagger was available in production.